# IllegalArgumentException: setTaskFromSourceRecord: TaskRecord is in a different stack than the parent of ActivityRecord

Tags: android, crash, illegalargumentexception, back-stack

I have a private company app and received an unusual crash report today. I haven't seen anything like it before, couldn't find any matches in Google searches, and so far have been unable to reproduce. The code in question went live in October and employees pass through it roughly 40 times a day overall when they punch out or switch job.

The app is compiled for SDK 28 (9.0) and the crash happened on 8.1.0.

I've modified the below snippets from original code to generify/simplify names and remove irrelevant code.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setTaskFromSourceRecord:
task=TaskRecord{f142380 #13 A=com.example.app U=0 StackId=1 sz=2} is in a different stack (1) than the parent of
r=ActivityRecord{120fce5 u0 com.sec.android.app.launcher/.activities.LauncherActivity t14} (0) at
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2033) at
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1975) at
android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:4822) at
android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1619) at
android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4621) at
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767) at
androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:234) at
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:881) at
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:995) at
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1084) at
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1073) at
com.example.app.PunchOutFragment.goHome(PunchOutFragment.java:234) at
com.example.app.PunchOutFragment.access$100(PunchOutFragment.java:50) at
com.example.app.PunchOutFragment$2.onReceive(PunchOutFragment.java:269) at
androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:313) at
androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:121) at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) at
com.example.app.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:48) at
android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1127) at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6097) at
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1791) at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441) at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

PunchOutFragment.goHome():

```
private void goHome() {
    Activity activity = requireActivity();
    activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), HomeActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent); // PunchOutFragment.java:234
    activity.finish();
}
```

MyApplication.onCreate():

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mWeakAppContext = new WeakReference<>(getApplicationContext());
    CrashHandler crashHandler = new CrashHandler();
    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    try {
        Looper.loop(); // MyApplication.java:48
    } catch (Exception e) {
        crashHandler.uncaughtException(Thread.currentThread(), e);
    }
}
```

Other relevant code called if active punch retrieved from server after login; server logs indicate that this was called about a minute prior to the punch out and crash:

```
private void selectPunch(Punch punch) {
    Context context = requireContext();
    Intent intentHome = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getContext());
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(HomeActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intentHome);
    Intent intentPunchedIn = new Intent(context, PunchedInActivity.class);
    intentPunchedIn.putExtra(PUNCH_ID, punch.id);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intentPunchedIn);
    stackBuilder.startActivities();
    requireActivity().finish();
}
```

Comment: There is something wrong, you are setting result and before a result is received by the parent activity you are starting a new activity in line 234. This not how activity for result work. Start new activity from onActivityResults

Comment: Good catch. The activity result and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is old code from the developer before me that I evidently ignored. The result only finished the parent activity, which is redundant with the flag. I don't think this has any impact on the main issue, but may never know for sure if I can't reproduce.